# HTML & Javascript Code within PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

How's that for a title!

Once again I find myself stumbling through lines of code that I don't really understand, and in doing so failing at almost every hurdle.

I have a php file xxxxx.php and what I'm trying to do is: from within a javascript function, set the properties of a div, and then execute some more javascript - I'm sure it's easy for someone who understands (but clearly not for me)

This piece of code works fine as it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
if (x==c_name)
{
return unescape(y);
}
}
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
{
alert("Welcome again " + username);
}
else
{
username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");

if (username!=null && username!="")
{
setCookie("username",username,7);
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
```

But then I want to insert this bit of code (which works fine on its own) directly after the 'setCookie' line:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:125px;left:-67px;z-index:10000000">
<script src="AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent('codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0','width','320','height','220','id','HTIFLVPlayer','src','HTIFLVPlayer','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=HTI_Skin&streamName=nigel&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=true','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','HTIFLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','wmode','transparent','movie','HTIFLVPlayer'); //end AC code

</script> </div>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I tried setting the div style in javascript using:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.top = "125px";
div.style.left = "-67px";
div.style.zIndex = "10000000";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

...but this simply threw the flash player (called with the 'AC_FL_RunContent' line) onto a new blank page, not within the existing page (as required).

Hopefully someone will be able to make sense of my ramblings.

Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your new code with `<div>` tag is inside main `<head>` tag - it won't work, try putting new code inside `<body>` tag.

another thing, you can't put any html tags inside `<script>` just like that. you have to `document.write` them somewhere.

**EDIT**

use sth like this after `setCookie();`:

```
document.write('<div style="position:absolute;top:125px;left:-67px;z-index:10000000">');
document.write('<script src="AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> AC_FL_RunContent('codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0','width','320','height','220','id','HTIFLVPlayer','src','HTIFLVPlayer','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=HTI_Skin&streamName=nigel&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=true','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','HTIFLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','wmode','transparent','movie','HTIFLVPlayer'); //end AC code</script> </div>");
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said, I don't actually understand how most of the code I crib and pick up from various sources actually works, and I hear what you're saying, but unfortunately (apologies for being thick) I still don't understand what I actually need to do to get the second bit of code integrated into the first.

Comment: insert the second bit of code after `<body onload="checkCookie()">`. you can't do this directly after `setCookie()` line, because: **1)** you can't mix plain html with plain js and **2)** `<div>` inside `<head>` won't work

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to understand, but what I'm trying to do is basically play a video in a div, but only if there's no cookie set, so I have to call the code to play the video from within the javascript that checks for the cookie (unless you tell me otherwise), and therefore if I put it in the body, then it always plays. Perhaps there's an easier way of acomplishing what I'm trying to do????

Comment: use `document.write`. I'll edit my answer to make it more readable ; )

Comment: Thanks for that. Strangely, the code itself is executed without a problem, but still opens the video on a new page. I'll keep on trying. Thanks again.